# Let $S$ be a surface, $K$ compact in $S$ with finitely many components. Does the frontier of a component of $S-K$ have finitely many components?

Tags: gn.general-topology, surfaces

Let $S$ be a connected surface and $K$ a compact subset of $S$ with finitely many connected components. Let $U$ be a connected component of $S-K$. Does the frontier of $U$ in $S$ have finitely many connected components?

Comment: $S=\mathbf{R}^2$ would be a good start. In this case, could we expect that the frontier of every open subset with connected complement, is connected?

Comment: If A is a connected subset of the plane and its complement is connected, then A must be simply connected and its frontier connected. But I do not know a simple proof of this fact. A would have only one ideal boundary point and the frontier would be the impression of this ideal boundary point. Rough idea